# Did AWS stop allowing PUTs to S3 locations more than one directory deep through the AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

On our various servers that have a product that includes a database, I create a job that runs a small script that makes a backup of the database, compresses the file, and sends it to S3.  I have one version of the script for windows / SQL Server, and a second for Ubuntu / Cassandra, but both use the `aws s3 cp` command to ship the file.  I noticed today that the windows / SQL Server backups have not happened since mid-February.  No error, just the file never shows up in the bucket.

I was able to re-create locally on my windows laptop by running the following command:

`aws s3 cp .\EmptyFile "s3://[prefix]-database-backups/[ServerName]/[DatabaseName]/emptyfile"`

By chance, I noticed that the Ubuntu / Cassandra does not include the database name.  Running that command works:

`aws s3 cp .\EmptyFile "s3://[prefix]-database-backups/[ServerName]/emptyfile"`

Running with `--debug` did not indicate an error.  In fact, the debug logs are suspiciously similar.

Why would the backups with an extra directory start failing all of the sudden?

Comment: Maybe the directory must be explicitly created before adding files to it? Maybe the script has S3 permission to add files but not to create directories?

Comment: The directory has over 300 backups already.  All of them created by this script / job before February.

Comment: S3 does not know directories. Meaning your issue is likely not that. Please check your error messages.

Comment: No error messages are returned when running manually, or through windows scheduler.  Even when running the commands with --debug